# "Napa" office app launching access required

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, office-addins

I'm developing Excel online apps using "Napa" Development Tool, using a newly registered account, currently in my 30 days free trial phase.

When I was trying to create an task pane app for Office on my Sharepoint page, I successfully created a project, and I was able to edit the code inside the online code editor.

When I was trying to run the project, by clicking on the "Run" icon on the left menu bar
[image],

the pop-ed up dialog indicates that the app was deployed on the website.

[image]

But, when I clicked on the link and it opens up a new browser tab, in which the webpage told me that I don't have access to that page.

[image]

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Also, it's not just that the Task pane apps are not working. I tried to create App for Sharepoint, Content app for Office, Task pane app for Office, and all of them don't work, telling me that I don't have access on the page when I tried to run them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

In the page indicating access required, post a new message and require access to the site.

And then in your own sharepoint.com site, edit the site and grant access to that specific message, then we can have the access to the app.